# Bash: write regex matches to separate file

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have the following text where I'm trying to extract several regex-matched lines into a separate text-file. The regex used is

```
^[A-Z][ \t].*$
```

and matches the required lines. The point I'm struggling with is separating the matched lines into a separate text-file. I tried sed, but was unable to achieve anything useful.

**sample data:**

```
272106 EGGXZOZX
(NAT-1/2 TRACKS FLS 310/390 INCLUSIVE
DEC 28/1130Z TO DEC 28/1900Z
PART ONE OF TWO PARTS-
A ERAKA 59/15 59/20 59/30 58/40 57/50 LOACH FOXXE
EAST LVLS NIL
WEST LVLS 310 320 330 340 350 360 370
EUR RTS WEST ETSOM
NAR NIL-
B GOMUP 58/15 58/20 58/30 57/40 56/50 SCROD VALIE
EAST LVLS NIL
WEST LVLS 310 320 330 340 350 360 370 380 390
EUR RTS WEST GINGA
NAR NIL-
C SUNOT 57/20 57/30 56/40 55/50 OYSTR STEAM
EAST LVLS NIL
WEST LVLS 310 320 330 340 350 360 370 380 390
EUR RTS WEST NIL
NAR NIL-
END OF PART ONE OF TWO PARTS)
```

**desired result:**

```
A ERAKA 59/15 59/20 59/30 58/40 57/50 LOACH FOXXE
B GOMUP 58/15 58/20 58/30 57/40 56/50 SCROD VALIE
C SUNOT 57/20 57/30 56/40 55/50 OYSTR STEAM
```

Any help or nudge in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

All the best,
Chris

**working solution:**

@anubhava had the solution working best for me:

```
grep '^[A-Z][[:space:]]' file > out.txt
```

Thank you!

Comment: You could use `grep` instead?

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit further? Unfortunately my command line knowledge is limited at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this `grep` should work:

```
grep '^[A-Z][[:space:]]' file > out.txt
```

OR using awk:

```
awk '/^[A-Z][[:space:]]/' file > out.txt
```

OR using sed:

```
sed -n '/^[A-Z][[:space:]]/p' file > out.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this solve it?

```
grep -e '^[A-Z][ \t].*$' inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex is more restrictive, it matches exact format of your lines, not just a single character in front of the string.

```
grep -Po '^[A-Z]\s+[A-Z]+\s([0-9]+/[0-9]+\s+)+[A-Z ]+$' file
```